# creating new directory when renaming package in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, package, rename

I try to rename the package name in android studio, but when i choose refractor / rename and put the new name, I get a new folder instead of renaming the first one.

I tried to do it from the menu 'refractor_this' but it didn't help.

*This is the folder i want to rename*

[image]

*Problem*

[image]

Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think because your android project is not correctly,so it can't rename ? Your project has not res,manifest etc.[rec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOwHq.png)